# Runtime Exception with Drools(java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.io.impl.ClassPathResource cannot be cast to org.drools.io.InternalResource)

Tags: java, runtime-error, drools

[image][image]

I have all the required JARS. Even though facing below issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.io.impl.ClassPathResource cannot be cast to org.drools.io.InternalResource
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:487)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:25)
```

attached images for the reference

Comment: Hello, is there any update on the above?

Comment: It is too little information.
You should provide source code that throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is too little information but I guess that you should create resource using the method ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource.

I had similar exception lately.
I tried to use following code:

```
final KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
kbuilder.add((Resource) new ByteArrayResource(data.getBytes()), ResourceType.DRL);
```

I had to change the second line to this one:

```
kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(data.getBytes()), ResourceType.DRL);
```

Try to make analogous changes in your code (note that you have classPathResource not byteArrayResource).